How can a record in Rails both be persisted and not exist at the same time?
I am trying to understand why I cannot find a file attached to a record so I have put a breakpoint at a certain point in my code during after_save callbacks (important to note when this is happening). Here is the output from making some calls during that pause:
0> self.inspect
=> #<BinSet id: 1131, name: "test upload", ...>

0> self.bins_table.download
=> Error: the evaluation of `self.bins_table.download` failed with the exception 'ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError'

0> self.bins_table.attached?
=> true

0> self.reload
=> Error: the evaluation of `self.reload` failed with the exception 'Couldn't find BinSet with 'id'=1131'

0> self.id
=> 1131

0> self.persisted?
=> true

0> BinSet.find(1131)
=> Error: the evaluation of `BinSet.find(1131)` failed with the exception 'Couldn't find BinSet with 'id'=1131'

0> self.save!
=> true

0> self.id
=> 1131

0> BinSet.find(1131)
=> Error: the evaluation of `BinSet.find(1131)` failed with the exception 'Couldn't find BinSet with 'id'=1131'

Recall this is happening during after_save, implying the record has been saved. It has been assigned an ID and self.persisted? is true, and yet it can't be found in the database. Where is the record at this point?

If you refer to the documentation for after_save (the linked doc is deprecated but this still applies to the current callback), you'll see the following:

Note that this callback is still wrapped in the transaction around save. For example, if you invoke an external indexer at this point it won’t see the changes in the database.

If you need the database transaction to be closed for your operation, I would use after_commit.
